# JQuery select name array with unknown id

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, arrays, jquery-selectors

I have multiple inputs as an array like this:

```
<input name="data[extras][1][id]" value="1">
<input name="data[extras][1][netto]">
<input name="data[extras][1][tax]">
<input name="data[extras][1][brutto]">

<input name="data[extras][2][id]" value="2">
<input name="data[extras][2][netto]">
<input name="data[extras][2][tax]">
<input name="data[extras][2][brutto]">
```

i got all extras with:

```
let extras = $('input[name^=data\\[extras\\]]');
```

now i would like to iterate through all to create an array out of it but i need for the id for further actions (the 1 or the 2).

i would like to achive something like this:

```
let id = $('input[name^=data\\[extras\\]\\[UNKNOWN ID\\]\\[id\\]]').val();
```

i hope anybody can help me.

Greetings

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: You can use two attributes, eg `$("input[name^=data\\[extras\\]][name^=\\[id\\]]")` to get all the IDs, if that helps.

Comment: i want the ID itself from data[extras][2] - i mean the "2" because this number changes and it's not always 2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can receive all ids in jquery like this

```
$('document').ready(function(){
  var values = $('input[name$=\\[id\\]]').map(function(){return $(this).val();}).get();
console.log(values); });
```

Comment: this almost worked for me. i have other inputs with id's aswell but this is a good starting point. i will try it later, thx

Comment: My pleasure. best of luck :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you could loop trough the inputs and in the loop get the id/index via regexp from the name attribute to query that [id] input?

```
data\[extras\]\[(\d)\]
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Unclear what your expected output would be, but you can easily loop over the collection of elements and parse out the number and the string.

```js
var inputs = document.querySelectorAll('[name^="data\[extras\]"]');
const grouped = Array.from(inputs).reduce(function(o, input) {
  const parts = input.name.match(/^data\[extras\]\[(\d+)\]\[(.*)\]$/);
  const index = parts[1];
  const key = parts[2];
  o[index] = o[index] || {};
  o[index][key] = input.value;
  return o;
}, {});

console.log(Object.values(grouped))
```

```html
<input name="data[extras][1][id]" value="1-i">
<input name="data[extras][1][netto]" value="1-n">
<input name="data[extras][1][tax]" value="1-t">
<input name="data[extras][1][brutto]" value="1-b">

<input name="data[extras][2][id]" value="2-i">
<input name="data[extras][2][netto]" value="2-n">
<input name="data[extras][2][tax]" value="2-t">
<input name="data[extras][2][brutto]" value="2-b">
```